# Doxygen call graph is not correct even though the preprocessing is correct

Tags: doxygen, call-graph

I have a function something like below. I run `doxygen -d Preprocessor` and check the preprocessed code and `function2()` is excluded. However, I still see the `function2()` in the call graph.

Configuration

```
Doxygen version: 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b)

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES

MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES

EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO

SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES

CALL_GRAPH = YES
HAVE_DOT = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES = YES
```

Function

```
void function(void)
{
    function1();

#ifdef filtered
    function2();
#endif
}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The given setup is incomplete as there are no settings for `CALL_GRAPH` / `HAVE_DOT` etc. shown and in the source code there are no functions `function`()` and `function2()`. That said this is a known problem as the call graph is calculated from the original source, not the preprocessed source.

Comment: The doxygen version is stated which is 1.9.1. I have added some additional configuration. So call graph is generated from original source? Is there any workaround?

Comment: As far as I know there is no real workaround, might be that one can construct something with the settings for filters and defining one's own preprocessing (But this will, probably, also influence the results of `SOURCE_BROWSER` setting).